# What does multiple %in% in a row test?

Tags: r, logic, truthiness

Consider:

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c")
b <- c("a", "e", "f")
c <- c("a", "h", "i")

> a %in% b %in% c
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I would have expected this to evaluate to `TRUE FALSE FALSE`, since the first element in each vector is "a". Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is first this operation: `a %in% b` resulting in `TRUE FALSE FALSE`. Then you basically do the chain `c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE) %in% c`, which of course, will result in all `False`.

You can try this to get the wanted vector of boolean (taking into account the position):

```
a == Reduce(function(u,v) ifelse(u==v, u, F), list(a,b,c))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If you want common elements, not depending on the position, you can do:

```
Reduce(intersect, list(a,b,c))
```

Comment: That is helpful, but it still doesn't explain what `a %in% b %in% c` does. What does it do?

Comment: It is explained in the first two lines ;)